# Is the degree conferral date the same as the completion of degree requirements date?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, application, greece

I am an MSc student in Greece, and this year I am applying  to PhD programs in US universities. My question is about my BSc degree.

Most universities require a conferral date as well as a start and an end date.
The start date is the date I was registered.
The end date is Jan 2020.

Now, my BSc transcripts state that I have completed my studies but I have not attended the graduation ceremony yet. The examination period (Jan 2020) during which I completed them is also mentioned. Furthermore, the date the last exam result was announced is mentioned as well - that is, the last course grade (that result was announced after January). Finally, I don't have the degree certificate yet, because no graduation ceremonies have taken place due to COVID-19.

Is completing my studies equivalent to being a graduate or to being conferred/awarded a degree?

I am worried that if I state that I have earned my degree, I will be required to provide the degree certificate (which I don't have yet) and that my transcripts won't be enough. Should I state that I am expected to earn a degree and leave the expected conferral date blank, or that I have indeed earned my degree, and give the date I fulfilled the requirements as the conferral date?

Comment: "Most universities require a conferral date as well as a start and an end date." Most? I've never seen this.

Comment: My transcript clearly states a conferral date - does your not?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Greece. I've seen most universities asking for those dates. I guess if you are not done yet you can leave the end of conferral dates blank, or give the expected dates. No, my transcript doesn't state a conferral date. It states what I mentioned above.

Comment: Then, *have* you earned the degree? In the US, you apply to graduate, which is mostly *pro forma*, but the official check you've completed the requirements. If I finished all my classes on 6/9/2017 but never filed to graduate, I would not have a conferral date, and would not have a degree. So the question is to *you* have you earned a degree? (The certificate is immaterial, at least in the US)

Comment: Well, I have applied to graduate (I did last Spring). But I haven't attended the graduation ceremony yet. Nothing regarding the graduation application or the conferral date is stated on my transcript. All the dates mentioned on my transcript are stated above.

Comment: Generally, a degree can be given to you at graduation even if you are not physically present.  However, if there was no graduation ceremony at all (because of Covid) then it's possible you don't have a degree yet.  You have completed all the requirements for a B.Sc., but you might not technically have a degree.  The culture in the US is that people overlook stupid technical requirements and, when they can't be just overlooked, grant exceptions to them.  Other cultures may differ.

Comment: We can't answer most of your questions (by the way, one question per post please) without knowing whether you  have actually received a degree. That's something only you can answer. Maybe there was a mistake - contact your registrar (US name) and ask.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Yeah, people are similar over here as well. The ceremony is treated as mere formality (I am enrolled in a master's program without having attended one).

Comment: This is a question where any answer would depend very much on the rules at the two institutions involved.  In general, if you've completed all requirements for the degree but are waiting for a conferal of degrees that happens on some regular schedule (say once a year) then there is likely to be another way in which you can get your institution to confirm that you've completed all requirements for the degree.

Comment: _Generally, a degree can be given to you at graduation_ — At least in the US, degrees are rarely _actually_ given at graduation.  Graduation is theater; diplomas are props.  Degrees are conferred by the registrar by setting a field in their database.  (At my PhD graduation, for example, I was given an empty diploma folder, and undergads were given rolled up sheets of printer paper.  I submitted my thesis two months later, and my degree was formally conferred five months after that.)

Answer (score 4):

> Is the degree conferral date the same as the completion of degree requirements date?

No, not necessarily. Most schools award degrees once per term (whether that's semester, or quarter). So if your last final was on the 8th, you would have *received* your degree on the same day as your friend whose last final was on the 10th.

> Is completing my studies equivalent to being a graduate or to being conferred/awarded a degree?

Again, not necessarily. In most places, you have to "apply" to graduate or similar, which as I mentioned in the comments is the formal check you completed the requirements. This means "completing" your studies doesn't mean anything until you've asked the university "I've done all these courses, can I have my degree now?"

For example, you could have done enough coursework to earn two separate degrees, but if you only apply for one, you only get one.

This very well could be different in some places (or for other types of degree). But it is certainly not a rule to rely on.

> I am worried that if I state that I have earned my degree, I will be required to provide the degree certificate (which I don't have yet) and that my transcripts won't be enough.

Nobody needs the certificate in the US, the (sealed, official) transcript will tell them whether you have a degree. If that doesn't say you have a degree, then they won't ask for a certificate, they will think you don't have a degree.

It sounds like there is a possibility you weren't conferred with your degree, because of COVID. You will have to follow up with your university to verify.